# Extracting frames from a video without a mouse pointer on it using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

I have a video created using ffmpeg, I need to extract frames (screenshots) from the video where the mouse pointer present in the video should not be present in frames extracted from it.

Sounds silly, but is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Is the mouse pointer already baked into images of the video you already have? If so, then you're out of luck, because at that point, the pointer is just colorized pixels.

Comment: yes, i need mouse pointer in the video. But i don't need it when extracting frames from the video.

Comment: Short of doing some advanced image processing, what you want is impossible. Everything that's "below" the mouse pointer is missing from the video. There's no easy way to separate the pointer from the rest. The best you can do is perform some automatic detection of the location of mouse pointer (similar to face detection), cut it out from the image and then use some form of advanced image restoration algorithm to interpolate over the gap. That's a seriously complex project, and if we were to address it on StackOverflow it'd be at least 50 questions worth.

Comment: You provided no details, so I'll assume you're using [x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab) input in ffmpeg. Use the `-draw_mouse 0` input option and re-capture.